# What is the contrast in "a warm coffee, though like a cappuccino"?

Tags: word-usage

I've been using YouTube dialogue to practice my listening skills, and I came across this sentence in a Kate Brock video.

> I'm gonna be making a warm coffee, though like a cappuccino.

I don't see the contrast between any two things. Both ideas imply something that relates to her making a cup of coffee. But I know I might be missing something here.

Comment: A cappuccino possibly contrasts with a 'regular' coffee. Don't expect standard, text-book grammar, diction or (even) common sense from people on Youtube.

Comment: Possibly the speaker expects a cappuccino to be hot rather than just warm.

Comment: In American usage—probably many usages outside of Italy—"coffee" with no further qualifier means drip coffee. Please use the "edit" button to show that you know what cappuccino is. And please provide a lot more context if you hope for anyone else to understand the meaning; I can't guess in what ways her beverage will be "like" cappuccino—small? frothy? It's even possible that "though" should have a comma after it, and stands in contrast to an earlier sentence. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I want to run out of cafés screaming (or murder someone, or both) if I see that people can buy their little ones a 'babycino', which seems to be an expensive little cup of warm frothy milk with cocoa sprinkled on it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Perhaps the simplest revenge would be simply to include caffeine in it...

Comment: @AndyBonner - but then the little bleeders would run about and screech even more than they do already.

Comment: As we say in AmE, "Damn right you're missing something". If you are trying to understand the basis for the word **though** it is to be found in the statement made immediately prior to the one you quoted.

Comment: If I could vote ten times to close this question, I would.

Comment: The source. It's no good saying the sentence is in a Kate Brock video. Who is she? Is she famous. If she is, I still wouldn't find the video. Give the link IN the question, please.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it is possible that the subtitles provided by the YouTube AI are wrong/misleading/ or even correct but before scaring off a visitor, who hasn't hurt or been arrogant with anyone, let's find out the precise source. *James K's answer looks good **though***

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Kate Brock is, it seems, a Facebook and TikTok 'influencer' aged about 15.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey   I count myself lucky not to have an account on TikTok, Facebook or Instagram. It's just Google = YouTube, which is bad enough.

Comment: Are you relying on auto-generated captions? Maybe that's not what she actually said. Do you have a link to the video?

Answer (score 0):

"Like" isn't so much used to *contrast* as it is to *compare*. It can also be used to introduce an example. So, there are two possibilities here.

In your example, the comparison is between:

- the kind of coffee the speaker wants (or is deciding) to make.
- a cappuccino.

As I'm sure you realise, a cappuccino *is* a coffee, but not all coffees are cappuccinos. So, one possibility is that the speaker is saying they want to make a warm coffee (ie not an iced coffee) and they are citing a cappuccino as an example of a warm coffee (ie the coffee they are going to make is warm in the same way that a cappuccino is warm) *or* they are citing cappuccino as a *possible option* (ie they may actually make a cappuccino, or maybe something similar).

Comment: We don't know what Kate Brock says. The OP could have misunderstood, Google's AI could have easily made a transcription error. We don't have the source, the link, nor do we know what the content of the video is. It could be a video of Brock making coffee and giving us the nail-biting step by step instructions. But who ever makes a "warm" coffee for themselves? Unless they choose to dilute it with tablespoons of cold milk. Although the local bar (in Italy) just downstairs from where I work does make their cappuccinos warm instead of hot if the weather is boiling outside.

Comment: @Mari-LouA while that may be true, the OP's question is not rooted in the transcription. They seem to think that 'like' is for contrasting, not comparing, and that isn't something they get from the transcription.